# Now that onBackPressed() is deprecated - How to handle onBackPressed/onStop/etc in a nice way?

Tags: android

Google is introducing [support for predictive back gesture (aka ahead of time back pressed callbacks)](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/predictive-back-gesture) and `onBackPressed()` got deprecated.
Many questions on SO and elsewhere focus on how to handle "are you sure you want to leave" dialogs. This is about something else though.

We are currently relying on `onBackPressed()` to clear a cache of possibly modified data on one screen, in the following Diagram referred to as "Screen X".

[image: Diagram regarding the issue]

###### Some ideas

At `onStop`, we could theoretically also run this code. But it's also called when opening Screen Y and Z. In these cases, the cache must not be cleared. Also, when the user is on Screen X and closes the app, this would trigger. This is fine.
As we can control how Screens Y and Z are opened, we could somehow cache a value that we check during `onStop`. But this seems very unnecessary and not "natural".

###### Other ideas (just keep using onBackPressed()):

It seems to work to simply keep using `onBackPressed()` and clearing the cache there, as we did before as well:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
override fun onBackPressed() {
    viewModel.clearFilterCache()
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

This very well could be the easiest way to solve it. To future readers of this code, it's immediately obvious in what case the cache is cleared.

Google just wants us to make predictive back gestures work, and for that it has to be forbidden/deprecated to have custom "should we show a dialog"-code in `onBackPressed()` which blocks navigation - but in my use case, this is not done. Ideally there would be a way to only allow business code to be ran in there I guess, but this is impossible.

##### Summary

The onBackPressed solutions seems to be the best to me. But I want to hear how other developers would solve this issue. I can't be the only one having this problem :D

Comment: Did you read the [section of the best practices specifically about running non-UI code on back](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/predictive-back-gesture#ui-logic)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you - I had seen the section, but not thought more of it before. I have tested a bit, using `onPause` for this works, onDestroy doesn't. It would be great to have a more extensive documentation there. The logging example did not make much sense to me.